# Why does a bool appear to take up as much memory as an int? C++

Tags: c++, memory, boolean

When i run this program at dev cpp, task manager says that it's about 79 MB. Codeforces with gnu c++ 4.7 says that it's 79112 kilobytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
const int N=10010,K=1010;
struct TPos
{
    int charge;
    bool ex;
    TPos()
    {
        charge=1<<30;
        ex=false;    
    }  
};
TPos d[N][K];

int main()
{
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

But when ex parametr is commented:

```
#include<stdio.h>
const int N=10010,K=1010;
struct TPos
{
    int charge;
    //bool ex;
    TPos()
    {
        charge=1<<30;
        //ex=false;    
    }  
};
TPos d[N][K];

int main()
{
    //while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

it's only 39536 KB.
I thought that boolean should use one byte. Why does it double the size?

Comment: [Padding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding)

Comment: You could try __attribute__((packed)) to see how it looks (but it's usually not a good practice for performance)

Comment: You can even reduce the memory requirement to `sizeof(int)` if you do not need all int-bits for `charge`. See my answer below. (Maybe one more or less power of 2 in charge does not make a big difference.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you pack a structure it will always take memory that is divisable by the word size(because of the memory allignment). You pack a structure by using `__attribute__(packed)` in gcc for example. See also [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html). Packing a structure may reduce the required memory but will almost certainly slow down the execution.

Comment: Right, it's possible, but probably not a good practice since it may break alignment and might increase chances for false cache line conflicts. See also - http://digitalvampire.org/blog/index.php/2006/07/31/why-you-shouldnt-use-__attribute__packed/

Answer (score 6):

Bool is a byte, but what you're seeing here is structure packing.

Your struct contains an int, so the compiler automatically aligns the structure to the size of an int to ensure that it's guaranteed to be properly aligned in an array. Otherwise, the second element of your array would have the int on an improperly aligned address - that could lead to decreased performance and on some architectures even to a crash.

You can explicitly turn structure packing off using compiler-specific pragmas and attributes, but you don't want to. If memory is a concern, consider using a struct of arrays instead of an array of structs.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the memory alignment. In this case, the `bool` is aligned in the `struct` to `int`. Meaning - there are some extra unused bytes.

This means, `sizeof( your_struct )` will give you `2 * sizeof( int )`.

You can do some experiments with this - check the `sizeof` the `struct`ure with some more `bool`s inside it (one after the other), check the size again by reordering the elements, etc. These are useful experiments to understand what happens. Also, research for struct padding and memory alignment would be extremely useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with structure alignment. On some platforms it's easier to address memory if it's multiple of 4 bytes. The compiler might pad your structure to make it easier to work with.
If I'm correct you can add another bool and you will see no extra space used.

Check compiler options on how to disable it, but note that the performance might suffer.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that `bool` usually uses one byte (it doesn't have to, though).

However, C and C++ are also allowed to add *padding* -- that is, empty space -- into structs to allow for alignment. It's a bit complicated, but basically when variables are aligned on particular boundaries, then memory access becomes much quicker.

In this case, adding the extra `bool` has probably increased the struct size from 4 bytes (for just in the `int`) to 8 bytes, so allow the structs to be nicely aligned inside your array. This all depends on your compiler of course, but you can use `sizeof(TPos)` to check.

Most compilers have extensions to request that a particular struct *not* be padded, even if this makes them slower to use -- you may want to look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the size specifier to reduce the size of your objects (See the `:` in the following code). If you do not really need the full int size for `charge` this could look like `TPosB`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include<stdio.h>
struct TPosB
{
    int charge : sizeof(int)-1;
    bool ex : 1;
    TPosB()
    {
        charge=1 << sizeof(int)-2;
        ex=false;
    }
};
TPosB b;

struct TPos
{
    int charge;
    bool ex;
    TPos()
    {
        charge=1<<30;
        ex=false;    
    }  
};
TPos a;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(int)" << sizeof(int);
    std::cout << "\nsizeof(a)=" << sizeof(a);
    std::cout << "\nsizeof(b)=" << sizeof(b);

    return 0;
}
```